# How can I repeat the process to display the current time?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a clock programm with customizable options but since I'm a beginner I'm running into some problems. I tried using the DigitalClock project but there's too many things in it for me right now
I looked into Timer and ScheduledExecuterService but I don't know how to use and where to place them.
I also tried to set a color to the background but the error was that it could be over ran.
How can I repeat the process in milliseconds, add a background and make the code lighter ?

```
public Clock() {
    initComponents();
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    int second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (second < 10){
        time.setText(" "+hour+": "+minute+":0"+second+"");
    }
    else if (minute < 10){
        time.setText(" "+hour+":0"+minute+": "+second+"");
    }
    else if (hour < 10){
        time.setText("0"+hour+": "+minute+": "+second+"");
    }
    else if (hour < 10 & minute < 10){
        time.setText("0"+hour+":0 "+minute+": "+second+"");
    }
    else if (minute < 10 & second < 10){
        time.setText(" "+hour+":0"+minute+":0"+second+"");
    }
    else if (hour < 10 & minute < 10 & second < 10){
        time.setText("0"+hour+":0"+minute+":0"+second+"");
    }
    else {
        time.setText(hour + " : " + minute + " : " + second+"");
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    }
```

Comment: Did you misunderstood `java` with `javascript`. They both are different.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it simple then you can simple do the following:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{
    final SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
    while(true) {
        System.out.println(sf.format(new Date()));
        Thread.sleep(1);
    }
}
```

But this might miss a millisecond entry in between. For example, it might go directly to `310` after `308` and miss `309` in between. But since we are talking about `1/1000th` of a second, in real life it is very unlikely to be noticed.

Your code will reduce to something like following:

```
public Clock() {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        initComponents();
        final SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
        while(true) {
            time.setText = sf.format(new Date());
            Thread.sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
          System.out.println(sf.format(new Date()));
      }
}, 0 , 1000000);
```

Will repeat in 1 ms.

Comment: This will repeat in `1 second` and not in `1 millisecond`.